# Putting diff restriction on same attribute present in 2 elements

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

I have an xml as below:

```
<Setting>
    <Error Num="1" Level="2"/>
    <Warning Num="3" Level="3"/>
</Setting>
```

Now for corresponding XSD i want to put restriction on "Level" i.e. "Level" in "Error" should have value between 1 to 10 and "Level" in "Warning" should have value between 5 to 15. How can i do that in XSD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: XSD displayed graphically using Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 BETA (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Setting">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Error">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Num" type="xs:int" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Level">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="10" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Warning">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Num" type="xs:int" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Level">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="5" />
                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="15" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```